# How to save a figure with high dpi/resolution using seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns
sns_plot=sns.heatmap(dataframe.corr())
sns_plot.figure.savefig('output_figure.png')
```

I have with the above piece of code, it worked for saving the image. But it is of less quality. How do I increase its dpi.

Comment: you can use .svg in the extension of filename

Answer (score 5, accepted):

adding dpi argument worked for this problem,

```
sns_plot.figure.savefig('output_figure.png',dpi=600)
```

Thanks.